# Convert 10gig to Gig on Cisco 4510R+E switch

Tags: cisco, switch

I have a cisco 4510R+E switch.  I know how to configure uplinks on other switches via the hw-module commands.  I am not seeing any options under hw-module to configure from 10gig to 1gig.  Hoping someone might know how to convert the uplinks on this switch from 10 gig to 1 gig? The IOS version is 03.05.00.E  15.0(1r)SG5.

Comment: What SUP do you have installed? dual or single as well?

Comment: Sure its the 7E and there is only one installed.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Found that the newer switches actually auto negotiate based on the GBIC rather than having to manually convert the 10gig interface to gig as the older switches did.

Comment: The GBIG/SFP/SFP+ almost always dictate the speed you're using (*some* supports more than one speed, but I haven't seen lots of them - always check the specs!)

Also always check if your device supports the GBIC/SFP you're using (I've had bad experience with some devices not supporting 100mb sfps, not great when the other end doesn't support gig... :/ )

Comment: if you could please add the sup module that you have installed and whether its dual or single sup - that would be appreciated. Especially for others who come with similar questions! thx